# Does Android Studio have column guide for commit message?

Tags: git, android-studio

There is a convention on git commit messages to define the maximum characters per line (50 in the first line, 72 on the rest). Sourcetree have an option to enable a line at a configurable position. [The image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lcYF.png) shows an example of a column in Sourcetree configured at 72 characters.

[image]

Does Android Studio have something like that to allow me do visually identify if my line is too long like the example in Sourcetree?

Answer (score 3):

Since [IntelliJ IDEA is the base for Android Studio](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2013/05/15/intellij-idea-is-the-base-for-android-studio-the-new-ide-for-android-developers/), you can use a plugin.

Here:

- [Git Commit Message Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10100-git-commit-message-plugin), which allows you to create Git commit messages with a structure defined within a template, that is customized by the user himself.

[image: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/files/10100/screenshot_17410.png]

- or [Git Commit Template Code tools](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9861-git-commit-template), which does have a [breakLines()](https://github.com/MobileTribe/commit-template-idea-plugin/blob/1970e9165ba68e0b65088dae4f01064f0cdf52a8/src/com/leroymerlin/commit/CommitDialog.java#L60-L84) function (so no visual aid here: the message will be formatted)

[image: breakLines]

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. JetBrains support for karma-runner commit conventions. Thank you very much @VonC